# Regexp to differ two similar URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

In JS I need to determine which URL pattern is loaded now.
Some pages have a URL like:
`http://example.com/sameword/otherword/`

Others have

`http://example.com/sameword/anotherword/123132/`

As you can see the domain and first part of the URLs are the same. I think I have to use regexp in JS, but have no idea how to make a correct regexp.

**UPDATE:**

- I cannot count slashes because there are other URLs with same slash
  count. I think I need a regexp with "sameword".
- I cannot use
  /anotherword/ because it always changes.

**UPDATE 2:**
Sample URLs:

`http://example.com/rentals/rossiya-moskva-i-obl/`

`http://example.com/rentals/rossiya-moskva-i-obl-moskva/1722224/`

`http://example.com/cabinet/objects/`

They all are different pages. I have a DB where i can store SOMETHING and call that SOMETHING from JS to start function on preferred page. For example, today i wish alert on first type of urls, tomorrow - on second.
It should be the same fixed JS code on all pages that gets SOMETHING and by that SOMETHING determine if it needed to run function on that page today.

Comment: why not `.indexOf('/anotherworld/')` ?

Comment: One could just use `.match(/\d/)` to see if it contains a digit.. are you trying to detect the word is changed, or presence of digits? Or are you just trying to capture the word to a variable?

Comment: Question description updated.

Comment: I will put JS on all pages, but it should do something differ on different kinds of pages. There are other pages on the website but i have no problem determining them because they have no similar parts.

Comment: So use `indexOf('sameword')` if that's always the same.

Comment: it's not really good. Regex to determine url will be stored in external place (eq. database). So i need universal way, regex i think.

Comment: @aokozlov do you seriously think that regex is more universal than indexOf?

Comment: Maybe he wants `sameword` out _http://jsfiddle.net/2ovtwhcw/_

Comment: Sample URLs: 
`http://example.com/rentals/rossiya-moskva-i-obl/`
`http://example.com/rentals/rossiya-moskva-i-obl-moskva/1722224/`
`http://example.com/cabinet/objects/`
They all are different pages.
I have a DB where i can store SOMETHING and call that SOMETHING from JS to start function on preferred page.
For example, today i wish alert on first type of urls, tomorrow - on second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to differentiate between the 2 URLs

```
http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/[0-9]*\/
```

[RegEx101 Example](https://www.regex101.com/r/uR2kX2/1)

Comment: That is EXACTLY what i searching for! Thank you very much!
regexes are: `http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/[0-9]*\/` and `http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/`
Thanx again!

Comment: How will this do the exceptions that you mentioned?

Comment: Barmar it works. I store in db this regex: `http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/[0-9]*\/` Javascript on all pages asks DB for that str and do test:
`var re = new RegExp("http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/[0-9]*\/");
var res = re.test(page_url);`
If and only if page is `http://example.com/rentals/ANYWORD/ANYINT/` it will return true.

Comment: Glad to help, next time just explain better what your needs are!

Answer (score 0):

Put the URLs in arrays -- one array for today's URLs, and another for the exclusions.

```
var todays_urls = [
    '//example\.com/rentals/rossiya-moskva-i-obl/',
    '//example\.com/rentals/usa-nyc/'
];
var todays_exceptions = [
    '//example\.com/rentals/usa-nyc/\d+/',
    '//example\.com/cabinet/objects/'
]
```

In the actual code, you would probably get this from the server using AJAX.

Then you can test the current URL against both lists.

```
if (!todays_exceptions.some(function(el) {
    return RegExp(el).test(document.location);
}) && todays_urls.some(function(el) {
    return RegExp(el).test(document.location);
})) {
    alert("This is a good URL");
}
```

Comment: it is ok, but /otherword is always changed. The correct urls are: `http://example.com/same_fixed_word/other_random_word/` and
`http://example.com/same_fixed_word/another_random_word/random_int/` And my JS should know what URL is now.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. What is the criteria you're trying to distinguish?

Comment: @AmitJoki Both URLs have `sameword`, so I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: @aokozlov You said that one URL has `sameword/otherword`, and the other URL has `sameword/anotherword`. My code tells which one of them it is. If both words can change, then what are you looking for?

Comment: @Barmar "I think I need a regexp with "sameword".
I cannot use /anotherword/ because it always changes.", so thought he needed a way to tell if sameword exists in the url, so made the edit. Anyway probably misunderstood.

Comment: Nope. todays urls are:

`//example.com/rentals/rossiya-moskva-i-obl/`

`//example.com/rentals/rossiya-piter/`

`//example.com/rentals/usa-nyc/`

but NOT

`//example.com/rentals/usa-nyc/1722224/`

and NOT 

`//example.com/cabinet/objects/`

that shoul be something more universal. without counting slashes in JS code.

Comment: I've generalized this to two arrays of matching URLs and exception URLs.

Comment: There are about 200k variants for `/rossiya-moskva-i-obl/` part. Are you seriusly think it is good to store it in array?

Comment: What are you going to do, make a regexp with `(variant1|variant2|variant3|...|variant200000)`?

Comment: No. Regex like `http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/[0-9]*\/` determinea ALL variations of URL with `http://example.com/same_fixed_word/ANYWORD/ANYINT/`

Comment: I was thinking you would leave out the `ANYINT` part, and just match the part before that.

Comment: And regex `http:\/\/example\.com\/same_fixed_word\/.*\/` determine ALL variations of URL like `http://example.com/same_fixed_word/ANYWORD/`. But URLs with `/ANYINT/` will not be approved by this regex. And that is what i need.

Comment: I've changed my answer to convert the array elements to RegExp.